# Does having multiple CSS files although small affect my page loading time?

Tags: html, css

**MY CONDITION**
I have multiple pages `index.html`, `menu.html` and I have single stylesheet `style.css`.
More than half of styling code needed for `index.html` is not needed in `menu.html`.

**MY CONFUSION**
Shall I create 3 CSS files `index.css`, `global.css`, `menu.css`? Each stylesheets focused for corresponding HTML document and `global.css` for global stylings

**MY DOUBT**
Will doing so affect my webpage load performance or not? Here, we are just loading multiple files but the no. of lines altogether has been decreased significantly.

Comment: It depends on how much css you have. It's not worth optimising if it's 10-30 classes. If it's a fairly large project then you might want to check it.

Comment: Its not a large project but my CSS has exceeded 600 lines and I am having difficulty managing it so I was searching for better option.
Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: There is no objective yes or no answer to this question. Will multiple CSS files affect loading time? Yes it may increase it. Will having a single large CSS file affect loading time? Yes, it will increase the first visit, but could decrease subsequent visits. It depends on a large number of factors. So large, books have been written on the subject. Whole careers have been made on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

As Heretic Monkey pointed out the performance of a website is a very complicated topic and there are no easy answers. Sometimes single large bundle is better, sometimes few smaller files.

If you would like to split up your CSS into multiple files during development but still publish it as a single file on the website, then you could use a css preprosessor like SASS. Check it out: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Anyways it sounds like your project is pretty small so I would not worry about this kind of optimizations yet. It is pretty crazy how much css (and other resources) are used on modern websites.

For example this is one of 4 css bundles that this stackoverflow page is using: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=c05ce93d5306

More important on the performance side is that the resources (css and others) are cached properly. That means that user only needs to download the css file once and after that the browser will use locally cached copy of the file. Caching can be configured on your web server or hosting service you are using.

Although keep in mind that caching might be bit risky and if configured wrong your visitor might end up running old styles or javascript. For example here is a good read on the topic: https://simonhearne.com/2022/caching-header-best-practices/

Comment: The preprocessor will not make decisions as to splitting the CSS or optimizing its loading. Indeed, it can make those decisions more challenging as you have to optimize for the preprocessor so that it is fast, and configure it so that its output loads quickly. Preprocessors have lots of good points, but making things simpler is not necessarily one of them.

Comment: Well what I mean is that with sass (or many other similar solutions) you can split the files during the development and then build it to single css file for production. That way there will not be performance hit for downloading multiple files but it might help with managing growing css code base.

Comment: The user is asking whether splitting up a single large single CSS file into multiple smaller CSS files will affect page load times. "Use SASS" does not answer that question. It may help with a different question, "How do I maintain large amounts of CSS?" but that's not this question.

Comment: Very good point. I will update my asnwer.